# Не получается настроить фильтр в html (django)

Tags: python, html, django

В общем это меню ресторана в котором должен выводится список блюд по заданной категории. И как вы уже поняли не получается вывести список. Пробовал разные методы, но зашел в тупик. Не могу понять, что нужно вводить в html, для того чтобы корректно отображалась информация. Help me)

*model*

````
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class FastFoodCategory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    positions = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(unique=True)
    is_visible = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __iter__(self):
        for dish in self.dishes.all():
            yield dish


    class Meta:
        ordering = ('positions',)
        verbose_name = 'Category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}'


class FastFood(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    is_visible = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    desc = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='food')
    category = models.ForeignKey(FastFoodCategory, related_name='dishes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    positions = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()


    class Meta:
        ordering = ('positions',)
        verbose_name = 'Dish'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Dishes'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}'


```
````

*views*

````
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import FastFoodCategory, FastFood
# Create your views here.
def main_view(reques):
    categories = FastFoodCategory.objects.filter(is_visible=True)
    dishes = FastFood.objects.filter(is_visible=True)
    return render(reques, 'main_page.html', context={
        "categories": categories,
        "dishes": dishes
    })
```
````

*html*

````
<section class="food_section layout_padding-bottom">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="heading_container heading_center">
            <h2>
                Our Menu
            </h2>
        </div>

        <ul class="filters_menu">
            {% for category in categories %}
                {% if forloop.first %}
                    <li class="active" data-filter="cat{{ category.pk }}">{{ category.title }}</li>
                {% else %}
                    <li data-filter="cat{{ category.pk }}">{{ category.title }}</li>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>

        <div class="filters-content">

            <div class="row grid">
                {% for category in categories %}
                    <div id="cat{{ category.pk }}">
                        {% for dish in category %}
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4" id="cat{{ category.pk }}">
                                <div class="box">
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="img-box">
                                            <img src="images/f1.png" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="detail-box">
                                            <h5>
                                                {{ dish.title }введите сюда код}
                                            </h5>
                                            <p>
                                                {{ dish.desc }}
                                            </p>
                                            <div class="options">
                                                <h6>
                                                    ${{ dish.price }}
                                                </h6>
                                                <a href="">
                                                    <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                                         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                                                         viewBox="0 0 456.029 456.029"
                                                         style="enable-background:new 0 0 456.029 456.029;"
                                                         xml:space="preserve">
                        <g>
                          <g>
                            <path d="M345.6,338.862c-29.184,0-53.248,23.552-53.248,53.248c0,29.184,23.552,53.248,53.248,53.248
                         c29.184,0,53.248-23.552,53.248-53.248C398.336,362.926,374.784,338.862,345.6,338.862z"/>
                          </g>
                        </g>
                                                        <g>
                          <g>
                            <path d="M439.296,84.91c-1.024,0-2.56-0.512-4.096-0.512H112.64l-5.12-34.304C104.448,27.566,84.992,10.67,61.952,10.67H20.48
                         C9.216,10.67,0,19.886,0,31.15c0,11.264,9.216,20.48,20.48,20.48h41.472c2.56,0,4.608,2.048,5.12,4.608l31.744,216.064
                         c4.096,27.136,27.648,47.616,55.296,47.616h212.992c26.624,0,49.664-18.944,55.296-45.056l33.28-166.4
                         C457.728,97.71,450.56,86.958,439.296,84.91z"/>
                          </g>
                        </g>
                                                        <g>
                          <g>
                            <path d="M215.04,389.55c-1.024-28.16-24.576-50.688-52.736-50.688c-29.696,1.536-52.224,26.112-51.2,55.296
                         c1.024,28.16,24.064,50.688,52.224,50.688h1.024C193.536,443.31,216.576,418.734,215.04,389.55z"/>
                          </g>
                        </g>
                                                        <g>
                        </g>
                                                        <g>
                        </g>
                                                        <g>
                        </g>
                                                        <g>
                        </g>
                                                        <g>
                        </g>
                                                        <g>
                        </g>
                                                        <g>
                        </g>
                                                        <g>
                        </g>
                                                        <g>
                        </g>
                                                        <g>
                        </g>
                                                        <g>
                        </g>
                                                        <g>
                        </g>
                                                        <g>
                        </g>
                                                        <g>
                        </g>
                                                        <g>
                        </g>
                      </svg>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="btn-box">
            <a href="">
                View More
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

Исходник html
```<section class="food_section layout_padding-bottom">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="heading_container heading_center">
            <h2>
                Our Menu
            </h2>
        </div>

        <ul class="filters_menu">
            <li class="active" data-filter="*">All</li>
            <li data-filter=".burger">Burger</li>
            <li data-filter=".pizza">Pizza</li>
            <li data-filter=".pasta">Pasta</li>
            <li data-filter=".fries">Fries</li>
        </ul>

        <div class="filters-content">
            <div class="row grid">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 all pizza">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div>
                            <div class="img-box">
                                <img src="images/f1.png" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="detail-box">
                                <h5>
                                    Delicious Pizza
                                </h5>
                                <p>
                                    Veniam debitis quaerat officiis quasi cupiditate quo, quisquam velit, magnam
                                    voluptatem repellendus sed eaque
                                </p>
                                <div class="options">
                                    <h6>
                                        $20
                                    </h6>
                                    <a href="">
                                        <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                             xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                                             viewBox="0 0 456.029 456.029"
                                             style="enable-background:new 0 0 456.029 456.029;" xml:space="preserve">
                        <g>
                          <g>
                            <path d="M345.6,338.862c-29.184,0-53.248,23.552-53.248,53.248c0,29.184,23.552,53.248,53.248,53.248
                         c29.184,0,53.248-23.552,53.248-53.248C398.336,362.926,374.784,338.862,345.6,338.862z"/>
                          </g>
                        </g>
                                            <g>
                          <g>
                            <path d="M439.296,84.91c-1.024,0-2.56-0.512-4.096-0.512H112.64l-5.12-34.304C104.448,27.566,84.992,10.67,61.952,10.67H20.48
                         C9.216,10.67,0,19.886,0,31.15c0,11.264,9.216,20.48,20.48,20.48h41.472c2.56,0,4.608,2.048,5.12,4.608l31.744,216.064
                         c4.096,27.136,27.648,47.616,55.296,47.616h212.992c26.624,0,49.664-18.944,55.296-45.056l33.28-166.4
                         C457.728,97.71,450.56,86.958,439.296,84.91z"/>
                          </g>
                        </g>
                                            <g>
                          <g>
                            <path d="M215.04,389.55c-1.024-28.16-24.576-50.688-52.736-50.688c-29.696,1.536-52.224,26.112-51.2,55.296
                         c1.024,28.16,24.064,50.688,52.224,50.688h1.024C193.536,443.31,216.576,418.734,215.04,389.55z"/>
                          </g>
                        </g>
                                            <g>
                        </g>
                                            <g>
                        </g>
                                            <g>
                        </g>
                                            <g>
                        </g>
                                            <g>
                        </g>
                                            <g>
                        </g>
                                            <g>
                        </g>
                                            <g>
                        </g>
                                            <g>
                        </g>
                                            <g>
                        </g>
                                            <g>
                        </g>
                                            <g>
                        </g>
                                            <g>
                        </g>
                                            <g>
                        </g>
                                            <g>
                        </g>
                      </svg>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-box">
            <a href="">
                View More
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Решил этот вопрос исправив код html

````
    <div class="container">
        <div class="heading_container heading_center">
            <h2>
                Our Menu
            </h2>
        </div>

        <ul class="filters_menu">
        <li class="active" data-{{ category }}="*">ALL</li>
            {% for category in categories %}
                <li data-filter=".{{ category.title }}">{{ category.title }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>

        <div class="filters-content">

            <div class="row grid">
                {% for dish in dishes %}
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 all {{ dish.category.title }}">
                        <div class="box">
                            <div>
                                <div class="img-box">
                                    <img src="images/f1.png" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="detail-box">
                                    <h5>
                                        {{ dish.title}}
                                    </h5>
                                    <p class="desc">
                                        {{ dish.desc }}
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="options">
                                        <h6>
                                            ${{ dish.price }}
                                        </h6>
                                        <a href="">
                                            <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                                 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                                                 viewBox="0 0 456.029 456.029"
                                                 style="enable-background:new 0 0 456.029 456.029;"
                                                 xml:space="preserve">
                        <g>
                          <g>
                            <path d="M345.6,338.862c-29.184,0-53.248,23.552-53.248,53.248c0,29.184,23.552,53.248,53.248,53.248
                         c29.184,0,53.248-23.552,53.248-53.248C398.336,362.926,374.784,338.862,345.6,338.862z"/>
                          </g>
                        </g>
                                                <g>
                          <g>
                            <path d="M439.296,84.91c-1.024,0-2.56-0.512-4.096-0.512H112.64l-5.12-34.304C104.448,27.566,84.992,10.67,61.952,10.67H20.48
                         C9.216,10.67,0,19.886,0,31.15c0,11.264,9.216,20.48,20.48,20.48h41.472c2.56,0,4.608,2.048,5.12,4.608l31.744,216.064
                         c4.096,27.136,27.648,47.616,55.296,47.616h212.992c26.624,0,49.664-18.944,55.296-45.056l33.28-166.4
                         C457.728,97.71,450.56,86.958,439.296,84.91z"/>
                          </g>
                        </g>
                                                <g>
                          <g>
                            <path d="M215.04,389.55c-1.024-28.16-24.576-50.688-52.736-50.688c-29.696,1.536-52.224,26.112-51.2,55.296
                         c1.024,28.16,24.064,50.688,52.224,50.688h1.024C193.536,443.31,216.576,418.734,215.04,389.55z"/>
                          </g>
                        </g>
                                                <g>
                        </g>
                                                <g>
                        </g>
                                                <g>
                        </g>
                                                <g>
                        </g>
                                                <g>
                        </g>
                                                <g>
                        </g>
                                                <g>
                        </g>
                                                <g>
                        </g>
                                                <g>
                        </g>
                                                <g>
                        </g>
                                                <g>
                        </g>
                                                <g>
                        </g>
                                                <g>
                        </g>
                                                <g>
                        </g>
                                                <g>
                        </g>
                      </svg>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-box">
            <a href="">
                View More
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>```
````